# Pass JSON string to object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, url, jsonp

I have two different JSON-urls that I want information from. The first URL defines the second URL.

How can I write JSON data to an object, and then put it somewhere else?

```
var sPreview;

function results(obj) {
    sPreview =  obj.response.docs[1].identifier;  
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = "https://example.com/search&output=json&callback=results";
     document.body.appendChild(script);

var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = '"https://example.com/details/' + sPreview + '&output=json&callback=preview"';
     document.body.appendChild(script);
```

sPreview just seems to be undefined.

Comment: Looks like `sPreview` will only be defined when you invoke the `results` function, which isn't being invoked anywhere.

Comment: Hm. When I do this I can write to a HTML class: 

`var sTitle = document.querySelector('.Song-title');

 function results(obj) {
    sTitle.innerHTML = obj.response.docs[1].title;
}`

So it seems that the results function populates sTitle with data which I can use, but only if I write .innerHTML for instance. Sorry, I'm very new to this, but there seems to be something really simple I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: @TomCoughlin Assuming the API properly implements JSONP, `callback=results` will cause the `results()` function to be called when the script is loaded.

Comment: @LeifRiksheim Are you sure the API you're calling implements JSONP? If it doesn't, you should get an error when loading the scripts you're creating.

Comment: Yes pretty sure, I have no problem fetching info and putting it in a HTML class by using .innerHTML. Btw, I'm using  [archive.org's api](https://archive.org/help/json.php)